# How do I open an app Based on an external Event

Tags: android

Use case: I have security cameras around my home (on zoneminder).  When an event is triggered (someone walks by the camera) I want to have some screen nearby the door and ideally push a notification to devices (hopefully android tablets) to display the camera view on all these connected devices.

I'm happy developing my own app if necessary (even better if such an app already exists).  But does Android support this functionality to allow an app to open based on an external event (some message to the app)?  I've personally never seen it (phonecall is the one exception).  I'm sure listening for events is easy, but I can see there being a rule not to allow apps to 'force open' in this way.

If there is a way, if you could point me to the class that would support this I would appreciate it. Thanks!

(If you have any other solutions for my use case, I'd be happy to hear them. Unfortunately, I'd like these tablets to run other apps too, so keeping the 'camera app' open constantly isn't really a solution for me.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure an app like tasker or llama would be able to do this for you.  Have you looked at those at all?  Edit, looks like Llama is now called Automate.  Looks very powerful for stuff like this.

Comment: So i was asking about doing this programmatically. But the more I think about it, lots of apps open based on events, just need to see how to do it from events from my camera.